# SSRS restricting running of reports within certain timeframes

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have multiple reports on SSRS running off of multiple stored procedures.

I was wondering if there was a way to restrict users to running reports within certain times e.g. only allowing a report to be ran between 9-10am and 2-3pm.

I can think of possibly saying to return an empty dataset if ran between times, but I didn't know if there was a better way of doing this?

Comment: In SSRS, no. In the SQL/Procedure the SSRS report runs you could.

Comment: Apologies - Yes I guess I meant within the procedure itself

Comment: you could also hide the reports from the web portal if you are using that. It won't prevent them showing hidden items and running it still, but it's at least a way to hint that the report should not be run. You can set it using something like `UPDATE c SET Hidden = 1 FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog c WHERE Path = '/my report folder/my report name'`

Comment: If it's just in the SQL, then why not just add a `WHERE` to check the current `GETDATE()`/`SYSDATETIME()`/`GETDATEUTC()` (as a `time`) is between the required hours?

Comment: Adding to @Larnu, you can then set the NoRowsMessage property on the report to say that the user is only allowed to run the report during certain times and display what the times are!